# Need help in constructing code for GAE Search Api

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, google-search-api

I have created Document, added it to Index and used the GAE Search API to search for a text successfully. Please find the sample code below.

```
search.Document(
    fields=[search.TextField(name='id', value=id),
            search.TextField(name='search', value=searchT)])

options = search.QueryOptions(returned_fields=['id'])
results = search.Index(name=_D_INDEX_NAME).search(search.Query(searchTxt, options=options))
```

Now I am unable to understand to to achieve these mentioned below: Some sample code would be really appreciated.

**To search for plural variants of an exact query, use the ~ operator:**
~"car"  # searches for "car" and "cars"
**To build queries that reference specific fields, use both field and value in your query, separated by a colon:**
field:value
field:"value as a string"

Comment: what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: I was looking for some sample code, as whatever I tried didnt work. Finally came to know from @Sebastian that it wont work in the dev_appserver (see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

When you add a document, you specify its schema by defining the fields of the document. In your case `id` and `search`.

To search for a term that only appears in a specific field you use the notation `field:term`

```
search.Index(name=_D_INDEX_NAME).search('search:programming')
```

For searching plural variants of a term you use the operator `~`

```
search.Index(name=_D_INDEX_NAME).search('~car')
```

Note however that this won't work in the dev_appserver.

Comment: Actually I tried this in dev_appserver and it didnt work. But as you mentioned I am going to check this out once again in the appspot.com. Thanks for your input. Also curious to know why it wont work in the dev_appserver?

Comment: Google haven't implemented Stemming on their development server. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/devserver